# Change color of div with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to change color of div within ajax ?
The div is called rowMain , but i have several divs of same as listing records.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit-productdescription").submit(function() {
                 var row = $(this).parent('.rowMain');
                 $.ajax({
                     type: $(this).attr('method'),
                     url: 'EbayBuy-ReceivedUpdate.php',
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                     success: function (data) {                         

                         row.css("background-color", "#787878");

               }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              console.log(" The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown );
            } });
           return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This does not update the row, i have also tried various options on divs within rowMain and still cant make them change.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#submit-productdescription").submit(function() {
      var row = $(this).parent('.rowMain');
      $.ajax({
       type: $(this).attr('method'),
       url: 'Update.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function (data) {
        
        row.css("background-color", "#787878");
        
       }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(" The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown );
    } });
      return false;
   });
  });
 </script>
```

```css
.rowMain  { display: block;width:95%;float:left;min-width:750px;background:red; height:auto;padding:10px;  border-radius: 3px;border: 1px solid #000000 position: relative;margin-left:2.5%; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:2px;  }
```

```html
<div id="main" class="rowMain">

<form id="submit-productdescription" method="post" autocomplete="off" class="received">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Id']?>" name="id"> 
     <input type="submit" name="submit-productdescription" value="Received <?php echo $row['Id']; ?>-<?php echo $row['Status']; ?>" class="btn" /></form>
          
</div>
```

Comment: what does `console.log(row);` give you? Maybe also show your HTML form too

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     var row = $(this).parent('.rowMain').get(0);
     $(row).css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
```

```css
.rowMain {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rowMain">
  <form id="submit-productdescription">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="rowMain">
  <form id="submit-productdescription">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="rowMain">
  <form id="submit-productdescription">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that is what i am trying to achieve , but i am obviously doing something wrong with my code, i added the get(0) and adjusted next line but still nothing , does my script need to change completely ?

Comment: this $('.rowMain').css("background-color", "#787878");    for instance changes all the rows in color so i know its just something minor i am getting wrong.

Comment: you should use $(‘row’).css instead of row.css